# Google Apps Script: Can't figure out how to add 7 days to a date

Tags: google-apps-script

I know this question has been asked many times but I still can't figure this out.  I am trying to add 7 days to a day.

I found an example [here:](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps-script/S3O_jioT96A)

This works and adds one day to the date as I'd expect:

```
 var d = new Date(dateRange[11]);
 d.setDate(d.getDate()+1);
```

But when I try to do the same thing with dates that I have in an array (I will eventually iterate through this):

```
newDates[12] = new Date(newDates[11]);
newDates[12].setDate(newDates[11].getDate()+7);
```

I am getting this error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot find function getDate in object Mon Jul 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT).
```

When I debug, the type of each item in the array is 'Array' not date.  The data in each array item looks like this in the debugger: [(new Date(1372658400000))]  I am assuming that to use the getDate function this needs to be a date rather than an array item.  When I expand the array item, the item nested inside, so item [12][0] is a date.  Do I have to reference it differently?

Following that line of reasoning, I tried this:

```
newDates[12][0] = new Date(newDates[11][0]);
newDates[12][0].setDate(newDates[11][0].getDate()+7);
```

But on the first line of that code above, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property "0.0" of undefined to "(class)@1176d9d1".
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might get this to work?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not simply like this ?

```
newDates[12] = new Date(newDates[11][0]);// take the relevant part of [11]
newDates[12].setDate(newDates[11][0].getDate()+7); // and make [12] a simple date object in the array
```

Out of curiosity, where is this array coming from ?

if you want [12] to have the same structure (an array in the array element) then use an intermediate variable:

```
var temp = new Date(newDates[11][0]);// take the relevant part of [11]
temp.setDate(newDates[11][0].getDate()+7); // set date to desired value 
newDates[12].push([temp]);// add into [12]
```

Comment: THank you!  This is what I ended up doing:                       `var temp = new Date(newDates[11][0]);
        temp.setDate(newDates[11][0].getDate()+7); 
        newDates[12] = new Array(temp);`

Comment: In answer to your question: the array is an array of dates that I pulled from a spreadsheet range.  The purpose is to be able to add future dates to it.